# No Awarded Bounty

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

I had submitted a question and put a bounty on it a little more than a week ago. I couldn't get a correct answer to my question and none of the answers had an upvote, so when the bounty closed, nobody was awarded the points.

What happened to those points?

Sorry about the duplicate. I couldn't find it where I originally posted it, but it was moved here.

Comment: "*If no new answer matches this requirement, no reputation will be awarded at all, and the reputation used on the bounty will be lost forever*".

Comment: Well, that seems silly. My question was valid, but nobody could solve it. Why is the bounty lost?

Comment: As far as I know, it's to encourage the "investor" to award it rather than taking it back or waiting for a better answer, and also to avoid clogging up the list of bountied questions.

Comment: Offering a bounty is like placing a wanted ad. You're getting preferential placement/enhanced visibility for your message, not a guarantee of an answer.

Comment: But its automatically awarded if an answer is good enough (given that it gets enough upvotes). I still don't think its done right, but its just my opinion. Thanks for your answers!